Is it possible to overload casting from base class to derived class in c++?
Is it possible to overload casting to derived types from base type for purposes of checking whether such casts are ok?
I am aware of the existence of dynamic_cast, which essentially does the same thing, however this question is more about curiosity than practicality.
Consider the following code:
struct base {
    template<class Derived, class = void /*add derived checks*/>
    operator Derived&() {
        static_assert(0, "called");
        //some logic to only allow safe casts
        return reinterpret_cast<Derived&>(*this);
    }
};
struct d1 :base {};
struct d2 :base {};

int main() {
    d1 d1;
    base& b = d1;
    //works as expected (fails with static_assert)
    {d2& wrong = b;}
    //never calls the operator Derived&, nor cares if it exists
    //explicit keyword doesn't do much either
    {struct d2& wrong = static_cast<struct d2&>(b);}
    {d2& wrong = (d2&)(b);}
}

This code generates with no errors, provided {struct d2& wrong = b;} is commented out, meaning that an explicit conversion does not call the custom conversion overload. Is there a way around it (apart from the obvious usage of dynamic_cast, or making a differently named function)?
P.S.
Note, that base class cannot have template arguments, because I want to store them in a std::vector<base*> and work with underlying types later.
Note, that figuring out how to ensure the cast is valid or not is not the goal of this question. Just assume this logic is already implemented.

static_cast along with template base class, lookup CRTP.

@πάνταῥεῖ could you explain what you mean in more detail? CRTP is when a Derived class passes it's own type to the base class as a template, according to my google searches. However, storing the Derived class types is not the issue I'm trying to solve. I'm trying to understand how to make explicit conversions call my custom overload. For this question assume, that the problem of determining whether the cast is legal is magically solved without passing a template argument from Derived types, granted the custom overload is invoked.

Note, that base class cannot have teplate arguments, because i want to store them in a vector. I will append this to the question.

static_cast will always just perform a downcast. You can write template <typename D> D& my_cast(base& b); and do whatever there. The calling code would then use d2& wrong = my_cast<d2&>(b);

That's a shame. Thanks.

@DiKetarogg  Note, that base class cannot have teplate arguments, because i want to store them in a vector. you can circumvent that by having an non-template base class of template base. That's mixing static and dynamic dispatch in one. Provided that you have store info  about to which template you want to cast. Oh, newer standards have some tools for that already  :P

@Swift-FridayPie I tried your suggestion, but it seems, static_cast doesn't care how many levels deep, it will perform a downcast anyway. Thanks for an interesting idea though.

@DiKetarogg cast operators OUTSIDE class always overrule anything else, that's true, that's by design. You act upon address of object here, not on object, so explicit conversions  aren't considered. Similarly you hardly can overrule upcast of pointers and references - that's compatible types. But I think you are just coming at whatever problem you have from wrong angle.

@Swift-FridayPie thanks for the insight. I think I'll just have to make a separate type identical to the base type, but not inheriting it to store different derived types in one place and avoid dynamic_cast at the same time. I wonder, if it's safe to reinterpret_cast one type into another, provided the data members are the same and types do not have virtual members? I need that to retrieve type information at runtime.

As for But I think you are just coming at whatever problem you have from wrong angle., the problem I'm trying to solve is how to get my most absurd ideas to work within c++ and how far can I go with them. I already have a way to store types and assign them an id at compile time, so the next obvious step is to put it to use somehow somewhere.

@DiKetarogg is that supposed be predictable readable ids? If not, there is already typeinfo. Sounds like you trying to build base for component-entity-subsystem

@Swift-FridayPie AFAIK, typeinfo is not part of c++, but a compiler extension (correct me if I'm wrong). I store type information as a simple int id. I increment it using a modified version of this compile time counter. The counter is incremented each time a new derived type is created and can convert ids to types and vice-versa. As for what I'm trying to build, I don't know, I'm just experimenting with the language. If a good entity-component-(sub)system comes out from this (unlikely), why not?

I meamt std::type_info : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid
